# Google heat maps - show weights on hover

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make an interactive heat map, that shows the coordinates and weight (value) of each data point when the mouse is close to them, and highlights the point in some way. It doesn't matter if the information is presented in a box, a tooltip, etc.

I drew an example of how it might look like (with 2 alternatives, a floating box or just text showing at the bottom):

[image: Example]

I'm new to javascript, but I've been looking for hours and I still have no idea how to do this. I think it shouldn't be that difficult.

Here is an example of something similar (but with whole areas instead of points):

http://blog.timesunion.com/capitol/archives/114554/2010-voting-patterns-2012-district-lines-bigger-majorities/

I don't think I can do it with markers, and I think it would be inefficient to create thousands of markers for that, also I'd like the infomation to be shown and hidden quickly, without clicking on the data points.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: On any modern browser, the markers are drawn on canvas tiles unless they are marked as `draggable` or the `optimized` option is set to false. Thousands of markers can be drawn without undue overhead on the client.

Comment: I actually solved it with markers, thanks!